# Extract data from wikipedia article

Tags: wikipedia

I am trying to extract an organized list of categories and their subcategories from a wikipedia article.
The article is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_academic_disciplines
It doesn't have to be dynamically coded into my site. I am also willing to manually extract the data with the help of a spreadsheet (`importxml`, `importhtml`, etc. statements).
However, I still have not found an elegant way to do either (spreadsheet extraction or via API) for the above article. (by viewing the source code you can see that `importhtml` with table as the query inputs all list items in a single cell and `importhtml` with list as the query doesn't differentiate between lists (ie: there's no way of knowing which lists are sublists of which categories)).
Can someone provide some suggestions.

Comment: I recommend you read [Wikipedia's documentation about writing a scraping bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot) before going too far with this.

Answer (score 0):

In Wikipedia "Category" is a specific term: to get the categories of that article via API, the query is the following:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=categories&titles=Outline%20of%20academic%20disciplines
```

But, as far as I can tell, you want all the URLs of the Wikipedia articles that are listed in that table.

There are several ways you can do that:
the simplest is to take the wikicode from the article ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Outline_of_academic_disciplines&action=edit)), paste it in a good editor (I recommend Sublime), and then you can use Search & Replace to scrape off the "[["" and "]]", plus adding in front of every article the URL

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/
```

With that, you can have the whole list of URLs to the articles mentioned in that page. 
Hope this is what you seek for (you mention some code, but I can't see any).